# Postfix to receive only to database email addresses

Tags: mysql, postfix

I have a standard Postfix server on one of my servers and I have not set up anything so far. What I wish to achieve is:
In a MySQL database I want to store email addresses that are accepted by Postfix. Everything else should be rejected.

I've read a lot of "HOWTO"s but now I'm getting very confused about it.
The steps are ??

- Create a database with a table containing id, address, status (like 1,anulu@example.com,OK)
- Create a cfg file in /etc/postfix to tell theDB connection details + a query something like: select status from users where address='%s'   (What is %s BTW??? )
- Add to main.cfg the following:  smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-recipient-access.cf
- Restart postfix and viola....

Not the last part, the "voila" isn't doing it for me. What did I get wrong in this idea?

I always get the following back:

`Mar 25 12:46:40 myserver postfix/local[32436]: 6D1C88XXX: to=<anyone@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.21, delays=0.15/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "anyone")`

While in the DB I have a row with: `id:1, address:anyone@mydomain.com, status:OK`

Answer (score 0):

Ha... Ha... NVM me. Once again, uploaded a question just to find the sollution pretty mutch right after. :D So what I was doing wrong is I've missed the luser_relay to forward all messages to an existing user and forwatd the local recipient map to the DB. To SUM it all up, here is what you have to do:

/etc/postfix/main.cf

- myhostname = mail.myserver.com
- mydomain = myserver.com
- myorigin = $mydomain
- inet_interfaces = all
- mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, $mydomain
- mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, MY.SERVERS.IP.ADDRESS/32
- relay_domains = $mydestination
- home_mailbox = Maildir/
- luser_relay = mailuser@myserver.com
- local_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/vmailbox

/etc/postfix/vmailbox

- user = dbadmin
- password = SECRET
- hosts = localhost
- dbname = mailserver
- query = SELECT id FROM places WHERE email='%s'

and NOW we can talk about any voila :)